# Контейнеры Docker на одном порту

Tags: docker

Есть несколько сайтов, каждый в отдельном контейнере (1 контейнер полноценный веб сервер), как сделать что бы ко всем сайтам можно было обратиться по порту 80 и 443? Docker разрешает запускать только один контейнер на 1 порт.

Comment: Отдельный контейнер с балансировщиком?

Comment: Данный вариант рассматривал с использованием nginx, но возможны еще какие либо варианты?

Answer (score 3):

Относитесь к контейнерам, как к разным машинам, можно ли реализовать это на разных машинах?

Единственный вариант - использовать балансировщик, например, Nginx(в отдельном контейнере или нет).
Запустите контейнеры на разных портах и настройте балансировщик.

[Nginx Reverse Proxy](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/)

Пример конфигурации:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  app1.example.org;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8001;
  }
}
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  app2.example.org;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8002;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать [сетевые адаптеры на базе драйвера `macvlan bridge`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-macvlan/) или аналогичные (сетевой драйвер `qnet` на устройствах от QNAP, к примеру) в ваших контейнерах, что должны торчать наружу. Таким способом можно *сделать контейнер участником той же сети, к которой подключен Docker-хост*.

У каждого контейнера с таким адаптером будет собственный MAC-адрес и собственный IP-адрес в этой сети (который может быть выдан её же DHCP) с собственным набором портов. Это устраняет конкуренцию за порты хоста, да и необходимость проброса портов контейнера на порты хоста в целом.

Но выставлять таким образом несколько машин непосредственно в интернет, для публики, возможно только если у вас есть в распоряжении несколько публичных адресов. Если же у вас всего один такой адрес, то вам всё равно потребуется единая точка входа именно на нём, без вариантов. Вроде балансировщика на основе nginx.

---

Готовой инструкции, к сожалению, не предложу, поскольку сам ещё плохо в этом разобрался и не могу гарантировать надёжность своих знаний в этой области, но я проверял на практике, что это осуществимо и работает.